# I am getting error: Undefined class 'required'. when trying to use required keyword

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am getting error: Undefined class 'required'. when trying to use required keyword.

Here is the code sample:

```
class Field {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final bool userEditable;
  final String title;
  Field({
    required this.id,
    this.name,
    this.userEditable,
    this.title,
  });
}
```

[image]

I am already using flutter's `@required` keyword but I trying to switch to dart's new `required` keyword.

Here is `pubspec.yaml`'s enviroment sdk line:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Here is output of flutter --version:

```
Flutter 2.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c5a4b4029c (2 weeks ago) • 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
Engine • revision 40441def69
Tools • Dart 2.12.0
```

Comment: You can't just use new language features on a whim. Update your minimum sdk constraint to `2.12.0`.

Comment: oh, missed that. thanks. if you can add that as answer i will upvote it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update your minimum sdk constraint to `2.12.0`.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```